# Error when running gulp serve, when implementing SPFX with Angular 4

Tags: office-365, spfx, angular2, visual-studio-code

Implementing SPFX with Angular 4 using the below link:
https://blog.hubfly.com/solutions/how-to-integrate-sharepoint-framework-spfx-with-angular-4.

Getting the below error after running the gulp serve command.

> [14:40:54] Starting 'serve'...
>   [14:40:54] Starting gulp
>   [14:40:54] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
>   [14:40:54] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 9.63 ms
>   [14:40:54] Starting subtask 'spfx-serve'...
>   Starting api server on port 5432.
>   Registring api: /getwebparts
>   Registring api: /*.*
>   Registring api: /workbench
>   [14:40:55] Error - [spfx-serve] Error: Invalid glob argument:
>   [14:40:55] Error - 'spfx-serve' sub task errored after 488 ms
>    Invalid glob argument:
>   [14:40:55] 'serve' errored after 514 ms
>   [14:40:55]
>   About to exit with code: 1
>   Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code not continuing!
>   Trying to exit with exit code 1